# Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon

Tags: c#, excel

I am following this walkthrough on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx)

And I am adding this code to my event:

```
private void CustomTaskPane1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Globals.Ribbons.ManageTaskPaneRibbon.toggleButton1.Checked =  
        customTaskPane1.Visible;  
}
```

I am getting the error that ManageTaskPaneRibbon is not defined in ThisRibbonCollection. Looking at documentation ManageTaskPaneRibbon is apart of Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common which I have referenced.

Any ideas on why this is not being recognized?

Answer (score 3):

That's the name given to the new Ribbon in step 3 of the "To add a toggle button to the Ribbon" section. You used a different name at that point. You'll need to substitute the name you used. (ask me how I found this question--haha!) :-)

Comment: Ok I'll bite, how on earth did you find this question

Comment: I fell for it too! LOL

Comment: Nice one... this caught me to! Tnx